# Tensorflow 1.0 training model uses exponentially more space

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 1.0 to train a DNNRegressor. Most of the training is already handled automatically by the new tensorflow 1.0 features. The model information is saved automatically in a folder. I call the train(filepath, isAuthentic) function repeatedly, with different training files, using a for loop.

The problem is that the events.out.tfevents files keep getting larger and larger, taking up space. I have gotten around this by deleting these files as they are generated, but the CPU still wastes incrementally more time trying to generate these files. These don't affect the results of training or predicting. Is there a way to stop these events.out.tfevents files from being generated?

I've noticed that when I run the python program for a long period, the events.out.tfevents file sizes start small and then get large, but if I run the training for several periods of shorter intervals, the file sizes stay small.

[picture of model folder, contents ordered by size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVzwD.png)

When I let the training run long enough, the events.out.tfevents reaches over 200 MB, wasting much time and space. I have already tried changing the checkpoint and summary parameters in a RunConfig object passed to the DNNRegressor.

```
def getRegressor():
  feature_cols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k) for k in networkSetup.FEATURES]
  # Build 2 layer fully connected DNN with 8, 8 units respectively.
  regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,
                                            hidden_units=[8, 8],
                                            model_dir=networkSetup.MODEL_DIR,
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                            optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
                                              learning_rate=0.001
                                            )
                                            )
  return regressor

def train(filepath, isAuthentic):
  regressor = getRegressor()
  # training on training set
  regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(filepath, isAuthentic), steps=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.tfevents` files contain events written by fit method. `DNNRegressor` saves at least histograms and fraction of zeros for each hidden layer. You can use [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) to view them.

Tensorflow doesn't overwrite event files instead it appends to them so bigger file size doesn't mean more CPU cycles.

You can pass `config` parameter to `DNNRegressor` constructor ([RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/RunConfig) instance) and specify how often you want summary to be saved using its `save_summary_steps` property. Default is to save summary every `100` steps.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent tensorflow creating the events.out file, you just have to comment that part of code that writes this file each time a new user trains the model.

In all the models, there are writers written in the main class to create these summaries/logs for further analysis of data, although it is not useful in many cases.

Sample code lines from Tensorflow Inception's "retrain.py":

```
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train',sess.graph)
validation_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/validation')
```

Just comment out the part of code creating the events.out file and you are up.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of newly generated Graph files for tensorboard.

```
tfFileWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.getcwd())
tfFileWriter.add_graph(sess.graph)
tfFileWriter.close()
```

Comment out these lines if you find them in your code and it would go away.